# How to add vertical space between question and line below

Tags: math-mode

Apologies for poor wording of question.

I want there to be more space between the questions (\task Multiply 0.5 by 10.) and line below it ($0.5 \times 10 &= \rule{4cm}{0.1mm}$). I have tried to use \vspace{} but it will not add vertical space between the two lines.

I usually use the \questions environment and paracols to avoid any issues like this. However, I am using another document class and not sure how to use the questions environment without the exam class.

Thank you for your help.

```
    \documentclass[
  a5paper,
  % pagesize,11pt,% both are default and therefore not needed
  bibliography=totoc,% bibtotoc is deprecated and therefore replaced according
                     % to the warning message
  numbers=noenddot,% pointlessnumbers is deprecated and therefore replaced
                   % according to the warning message
  headings=normal,% normalheadings is deprecated and therefore replaced
                  % according to the warning message
  DIV=9,twoside=false,
  headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,% see the KOMA-Script manual
headheight=87pt,% not used, to not lower the header, but this results in a warning
footheight=52pt, % no longer needed, because the lines are not part of the footer
]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{1.05}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}% moved according to the KOMA-Script manual, because it
                      % makes no sense before changing font an linespread.

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[%
  autoenlargeheadfoot=false,% only warn but don't change height reserved for header or footer  
  manualmark,% or maybe automark, this is not clear due to missing information
             % in the question.
  plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,% See the KOMA-Script manual for more information
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 total={100mm,200mm}, %not sue what this line is either.
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headsep=2mm,
 }

\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}
     \item Fill in the blanks.
            \begin{tasks}[label=\alph*), label-width=1.5em, after-item-skip=10pt](1)
                \task Multiply 0.5 by 10.
                    
                    $0.5 \times 10 &= \rule{4cm}{0.1mm}$
                
                \task Multiply 0.11 by 10.
    
                    $0.11 \times 10 &= \rule{4cm}{0.1mm}$
                    
            \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You could add e.g. `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip`?

Comment: Ah! Of course, I have definitely used this before. THank you!

Comment: Your code does not compile without error (because of the `&` in the inline math code). Maybe you want: `\[ 0.5 \times 10 = \rule{4cm}{0.1mm} \]`. BTW: `\vspace{…}` works, but you still need the empty line (the paragraph). Otherwise the space is delayed and therefore added before the next `\task`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locally force a line height with an invisible vertical rule (rule of `0pt` width). To assure, for example, `1cm` for the answer, try

```tex
\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{4cm}{0.1mm}
```

Since there is many answer lines, it's better to define a dedicated macro

```tex
\newcommand*{\answerline}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{4cm}{0.1mm}
```

Better, add an optional argument, if a larger answer line is locally needed

```
\newcommand*{\answerline}[1][4cm]{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{#1}{0.1mm}}
```

Full code

```tex
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  % pagesize,11pt,% both are default and therefore not needed
  bibliography=totoc,% bibtotoc is deprecated and therefore replaced according
                     % to the warning message
  numbers=noenddot,% pointlessnumbers is deprecated and therefore replaced
                   % according to the warning message
  headings=normal,% normalheadings is deprecated and therefore replaced
                  % according to the warning message
  DIV=9,twoside=false,
  headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,% see the KOMA-Script manual
headheight=87pt,% not used, to not lower the header, but this results in a warning
footheight=52pt, % no longer needed, because the lines are not part of the footer
]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{1.05}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}% moved according to the KOMA-Script manual, because it
                      % makes no sense before changing font an linespread.

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[%
  autoenlargeheadfoot=false,% only warn but don't change height reserved for header or footer
  manualmark,% or maybe automark, this is not clear due to missing information
             % in the question.
  plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,% See the KOMA-Script manual for more information
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 total={100mm,200mm}, %not sue what this line is either.
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headsep=2mm,
 }

\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand*{\answerline}[1][4cm]{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{#1}{0.1mm}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}
     \item Fill in the blanks.
            \begin{tasks}[label=\alph*), label-width=1.5em,
              after-item-skip=10pt](1)

                \task Multiply 0.5 by 10.

                    $0.5 \times 10 = \answerline$

                \task Multiply 0.11 by 10.

                    $0.11 \times 10 = \answerline[6cm]$
            \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

 \end{document}
```

[image: answerline macro]